# Is there a way to isolate a library that is blocking on async code

Tags: c#, asynchronous

It is widely known that blocking on async code is a bad idea. As shown here and numerous other places. http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

But if using a third party library that does this anyway, is there a way to isolate the problem by providing a proper synchronization context or another fix without rewriting the library.

The offender in this case is: https://github.com/launchdarkly/.net-client/blob/master/src/LaunchDarkly.Client/FeatureRequestor.cs and it seems to be causing us some problems.

Comment: Some problems = deadlock?

Comment: Can you submit a pull request for that project?

Comment: That is the assumption is we are getting deadlocks but is quite hard to verify

Comment: @Gusdor I certainly could. I don't know if they would accept it, but it would probably have to a breaking change which would require a major version bumb so getting that ready soon seems unlikely.

Comment: Well it's not really breaking change. They make async call and then immediatly block on Result, so most likely they just have no idea what they are doing. They could just make synchronous call with the same result.

Comment: @Evk but by making it synchronious they would have to use a different httpclient which is certainly possible but no small tweak

Comment: @EsbenSkovPedersen the issue is that they are using `ConfigureAwait` incorrectly at line 27. `using (var responseTask = httpClient.GetAsync(uri).ConfigureAwait(false))` would fix it.

Comment: @Gusdor, rewriting that code using synchronous methods would fix it, not some hacks.

Comment: @Evk Agreed. I'm simply proposing a minimal change that doesn't require a new dependency (`HttpClient` has no synchronous Get method that I can see) and doesn't changing the signature (using `async/await` properly is the holy grail if you ask me)

Comment: So basically they are calling ConfigureAwait but throwing the result away?

Comment: @EsbenSkovPedersen That is correct. You can see it happening on lines 29 and 33. In the article you linked, My Cleary await the _result of_ `ConfigureAwait`

Comment: @Gusdor I'm a little confused by what you mean by my Cleary, but I assume you mean something to the effect that the result of ConfigureAwait should be awaited, but the problem is that we are not in an async method so we can not use await. We can however use responseTask.ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult() . Is that what you meant?

Comment: @EsbenSkovPedersen That is correct. The significant change is that the task will no longer attempt to post back to the UI before making the result available. Perhaps you should open an issue on the project and we can discuss it there?

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation is to call into the library from a worker thread.

This will provide the library with the default synchronization context and will no longer marshal to a single thread.

This is not a recommended workaround but it should do the trick.

Comment: Do you mean by wrapping any or some of the calls with Task.Run ?

Comment: @EsbenSkovPedersen Yes.